# Small problems when dynamically resizing a picturebox (tooltip delay, 'blinking')

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Help please elegantly solve a couple of problems in my small project. I'm developing a small program in c # (WinForms), which uses pictureboxes instead of buttons. I added a small feature like an 'animation' to them: when you mouse over them they decrease in size, when the mouse goes away they return to their original state. Actually, I have two problems here:

1. If the mouse is brought to the very edge, the picturebox will be decreased, but if the mouse is out of the current size of the picturebox, it's size will be returned back. And so on. Such a kind of 'blinking' turns out.
2. And more importantly, I have tooltips attached to these pictureboxes. And if you move the mouse over the picturebox, it will decrease in size and the tooltip will not be called. It will take to move the cursor a little without going beyond the picturebox so the tooltip will appear. And this behavior is counterintuitive.

Here's the code:

```
    private void IconReduce(PictureBox picturebox)
    {
        originalLocation = picturebox.Location;
        originalSize = picturebox.Size;
        picturebox.Location = new Point(picturebox.Location.X + 2, picturebox.Location.Y + 2);
        picturebox.Size = new Size(picturebox.Size.Width - 4, picturebox.Size.Height - 4);
    }

    private void IconNormal(PictureBox picturebox)
    {
        picturebox.Location = new Point(originalLocation.X, originalLocation.Y);
        picturebox.Size = new Size(originalSize.Width, originalSize.Height);
    }

    private void pb_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IconReduce(sender as PictureBox);
    }

    private void pb_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IconNormal(sender as PictureBox);
    }
```

Comment: You should not change the size of the control/picturebox. If you want to have some kind of visible effect change the content of the picturebox. Like showing a slightly smaller version of the image or something like that.

Comment: I agree with @Ralf I think you'd be better off changing the size of the image on the picturebox, and leave the size of the picturebox itself untouched.  Would this work for what you're trying to do?  Or is there some reason you need the picturebox size to change?

Comment: These are common issues and common wisdom say it isn't worth the hassle. Btw: You don't need a picturebox to display an image. Button can do that just as well and with FlatStyle offers nice features..

Comment: Thank you all guys! I finally figured out how to fix my code with resizing the content of control instead of reducing the control itself and now everything is working properly. That's great, thank you so much!